Is an Ethiopian visa on arrival available for an Indian passport holder?
Is an Ethiopian visa on arrival for an Indian passport holder?

You can check on the IATA website. To answer we might need more information eg intended length of stay

It might depend on the reason for the visit, too: tourism, business, or long term work.

Yes Indians can enter with visa on arrival, you need to apply for an e-visa  https://www.evisa.gov.et/ and this is what says on the govt website that shows India as Visa on Arrival https://www.evisa.gov.et/information/touristOnArrivalVisa
I looked into the embassy website in Delhi the document also suggests visa on arrival check this page http://www.ethiopianembassy.org.in/download/Visa-document-requirements.pdf
